# Error with PostgreSQL + Sequelize + array_append

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am having problems with the next code

```
    let user =  req.user.id;

    await MyTable.update(
        {'interested': Sequelize.fn('array_append', Sequelize.col('interested'), user)},
        {'where': {'slug': req.params.slug}}
    );
```

The error stack trace is the next

```
[0] Unhandled rejection TypeError: values.map is not a function
[0]     at ARRAY._value (D:\development_learning\Languages\Node\Bootcamp Node.js\practices\track-project\node_modules\Sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\data-types.js:458:19)
[0]     at ARRAY._bindParam (D:\development_learning\Languages\Node\Bootcamp Node.js\practices\track-project\node_modules\Sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\data-types.js:492:35)
[0]     at ARRAY.bindParam (D:\development_learning\Languages\Node\Bootcamp Node.js\practices\track-project\node_modules\Sequelize\lib\data-types.js:29:19)
```

I think that the problem is related to the execution of the function

```
Sequelize.fn('array_append', Sequelize.col('interested'), user)
```

I am not finding a good documentation in Sequelize.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try and change `user` to `[user]` on the `Sequelize.fn` parameter

Comment: @PedroPinto the same happens.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

objects still need to be stringified, trough, so they don't get inserted as "[object Object]"

```
var user = JSON.stringify({

    //your key and value
});

await MyTable.update(
    { interested: sequelize.fn('array_append', models.sequelize.col('interested'), user) },
    { where: { 'slug': req.params.slug } }
);
```

Comment: Hi, it still not work. In the model the column "interested" is defined as:

    interested: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.INTEGER),
        defaultValue: []
    }

Comment: I tried it, but it still not working. I get the same error. I am testing with     

var user = JSON.stringify({
        1:1
    });